# How to add double quotes in string in gwt?

Tags: java, gwt

I want to add double quotes to a string like `How are you "Anil"`. I tried in gwt, but the double quotes display like question marks. `How are you ?Anil?`. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: There is an encoding problem somewhere, but we cannot help without more information.

Comment: Show to code you used to try and accomplish this.

Comment: Where are you using it client side or server side?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
String str="How are you \"anil\" ?";
```